# Fetch Array of objects using array as predicate - Coredata iOS

Tags: ios, mysql, arrays, core-data

I have two tables in the coredata. unReadMessages & ReadMessages.

Some of the unReadMessages records are available in ReadMessages table. I need to fetch those records from ReadMessages table. How can i write the fetchRequest for this.

unReadMessages & ReadMessages Fields are
`date, body, roomId.` Note that the 'date' field value will be same in both tables. So we can get the records using date field.

```
 NSArray *unReadMessages = [self fetchunReadMessages:roomId];
    if (unReadMessages.count > 0){
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        NSArray *readMessages = //Get messages from the readMessages table using unReadMessages Array.

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you keep a read status in core data table, It would be very easy to fetch in that case.

For your case probably you need to use compound predicate statement.

Comment: The table name which i mentioned is only for informational purpose. My actual table name is different. In this case 'readMessages' table is handled by some other framework. I am handling only 'unReadMessages' table. But i want to delete the records from the 'readMessages' table bases on the fetchrequest.

Comment: Ok, then did you try to form the predicate using "OR". I guess you can fetch those records by setting predicate like "date1 OR date2" like wise.

Comment: Better you go with predicate on body, if you need to track messages for all rooms and past dates

Comment: You can use the `in` keyword. Since you are using the date property as the identifier, I think you can use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date in %@",
        <dates of unread messages, ex. [unreadMessages valueForKey:@"date"]>]`